# Check bitfield value in static assert?

Tags: c++, c++20

I wrote a library that requires little endian and bitfields to be ordered from low to high

I run similar code at runtime to check it. I was wondering if I could do this at compile time?

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

struct A {
    uint64_t a : 4, b : 5, c:55;
    A()=default;
    //constexpr A(uint64_t value) { memcpy(this, &value, 8); }
    A(uint64_t value) { memcpy(this, &value, 8); }
};
static_assert(sizeof(A) == 8);

int main() {
    A test(0x3F3);
    assert(test.a == 3);
    assert(test.b == 0x1F);
    assert(test.c == 1);
}
```

Comment: I think using a memcpy would help but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in a constexpr

Comment: I've run into portability problems with bitfields in the past, with shared code between Windows NT 3.5 and DEC Alpha machines.  Our solution was to do our own shifts and masks, encapsulated in the few classes that had to worry about that kind of thing.  (If the code didn't need to be cross-platform, we would have just used bitfields with that single target platforms behavior, and accommodate for it.)

Comment: Note that bitfield layouts are implementation defined. So the layout could be `abc` or `cba` or `cab` or ... and c could be big, little or middle endian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the `memcpy` with `bit_cast` to make your constructor `constexpr`:

```cpp
#include <bit>
#include <cstdint>

struct A {
    uint64_t a : 4, b : 5, c:55;
    A()=default;
    constexpr A(uint64_t value) { *this = std::bit_cast<A>(value); }
};

static_assert(A(0x3F3).a == 3);
static_assert(A(0x3F3).b == 0x1F);
static_assert(A(0x3F3).c == 1);
```

It should optimize to the same thing as `memcpy`.

Note that older versions of some compilers don't support `bit_cast` to types
with bit fields. Probably the best solution for these is to keep the `memcpy` and use a build tool to check this before you compile.

Comment: TY, that worked in gcc but not in clang. It's fine because all my optimize builds I use gcc

Comment: @Cal Fwiw: clang says _"constexpr bit_cast involving bit-field is not yet supported"_ which is promising, so combining the endian check + a `bit_cast` check should be _the_ way to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

For endianess, just use the C++20 [`std::endian`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian) check:

```
#include <bit>

struct A {
    static_assert(std::endian::native == std::endian::little);
    // ...
};
```

If this compiles, the target is using little endian.

For [bit-fields](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field):

> The following properties of bit-fields are implementation-defined:
>
> - The value that results from assigning or initializing a signed bit-field with a value out of range, or from incrementing a signed bit-field past its range.
> - Everything about the actual allocation details of bit-fields within the class object
>
>   - For example, on some platforms, bit-fields don't straddle bytes, on others they do
>   - Also, on some platforms, bit-fields are packed left-to-right, on others right-to-left

Comment: That's pretty good. Its too bad bitfields are getting in my way

Comment: @Cal Yeah, I was a bit quick on the trigger.  I'll see if I can come up with something for that.

Answer (score 0):

> if I could do this at compile time?

No, you can't. Not only that, but your class is not portable and compiler and platform specific.

Rewrite your class to be using bit masks and accessors and getters for each field, and it will be portable and test-able staticallly.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    uint64_t value;
    constexpr A(uint64_t value) : value(value) { }
    constexpr uint64_t get(size_t offset, size_t len) const {
        return (value >> offset) & ((1ull << len) - 1);
    }
    constexpr uint64_t a() const { return get(0, 4); }
    constexpr uint64_t b() const { return get(4, 5); }
    constexpr uint64_t c() const { return get(9, 55); }
};
static_assert(sizeof(A) == 8);

int main() {
    static_assert(A(0x3F3).a() == 3);
    static_assert(A(0x3F3).b() == 0x1f);
    static_assert(A(0x3F3).c() == 1);
}
```

Comment: I can't change the entire codebase to use getters and setters and other codebases share the library I'm working on. I would have to change those too and I can't

Comment: Surely you are right. Note that with a class, like `iterator`/`const_iterator` for containers, it's the same as adding `()` everywhere in your code to references to members.

Comment: Someone found a gcc solution